# How to create a circle with divided borders in CSS and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm brand new to HTML/CSS and Javascript. I've gone through codeacademy's tutorials but found that they were too basic and did not help with the task that I have to accomplish.

What I basically am trying to do is create a circle with 12 divided parts in the border. The closest thing that I found to what I want is the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/hywrc3qv/

```
  ctx = $('#c')[0].getContext('2d');


function update(E) {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 224, 224);
if (E === false) {
    mx = 112;
    my = 112;
} else {
    mx = E.pageX - $('#c').offset().left;
    my = E.pageY - $('#c').offset().top;
}

mangle = (-Math.atan2(mx-112, my-112)+Math.PI*2.5)%(Math.PI*2);
mradius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mx - 112, 2) + Math.pow(my - 112, 2));

$('#i').val("Not over any region");
$('#link').attr('href', '');
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    angle = -Math.PI / 8 + i * (Math.PI / 4);

    if (((mangle > angle && mangle < (angle + Math.PI / 4)) || (mangle > Math.PI*15/8 && i==0)) && mradius<=112 && mradius>=69) {
        ctx.fillStyle="#5a5a5a";
        $('#i').val("In region "+i);
        $('#link').attr('href', '#'+i);
    } else {
        ctx.fillStyle="#4c4c4c";
    }

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(112, 112);
    //ctx.lineTo(112+Math.cos(angle)*112, 112+Math.sin(angle)*112);
    ctx.arc(112, 112, 112, angle, angle + Math.PI / 4, false);
    ctx.lineTo(112, 112);
    ctx.fill();


}

ctx.fillStyle = "#f2f2f2";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(112, 112, 69, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.fill();
}

update(false);
```

Except that it is divided into 8 parts. I'm having some trouble understanding the calculations and how it would be possible to access each divided segment and change the colour (or even animate it).

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: so when someone clicks a pie in the chart, the block above should change color?

Comment: Wouldn't an SVG be simpler?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hywrc3qv/2/

Comment: @emporio hey thanks for replying, no this was just a code snippet that I had found on the internet, I should have removed the code that generated the reactangle, sorry about that

Comment: @CalebAnthony Thanks so much! If possible, could you explain some of the calculations that are being done?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rL1mgveb/1/ replaced required number with a variable. Just plug in the required number

Comment: @Paulie_D Do you know why it highlights region 0 even if you are on a different one?

Comment: No....I just tinkered with the existing code...much like the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I don't necessarily know all the calculations that went into it.

I did some fiddling, and here's a modified version that you can plug any number into and it'll create a circle with that many slices.

Essentially, I took all the instances of `8` and then of `4` and replaced them with new numbers, just using a new argument of `num` and the following variables:

**JavaScript**

```
size = num
hSize = num / 2
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oh7u6je2/)